# How does Internal`PolynomialFunctionQ work?

Tags: performance-tuning, undocumented, built-in-symbols

I found that `` Internal`PolynomialFunctionQ `` performs much better than `PolynomialQ`.

Here is a huge random polynomial in 12 variables with around 120k terms:

```
myPoly = Product[(RandomInteger[{-2, 2}] + RandomInteger[{-2, 2}] a + 
  RandomInteger[{-6, 6}] b + RandomInteger[{-6, 6}] c + 
  RandomInteger[{-6, 6}] d + RandomInteger[{-6, 6}] e + 
  RandomInteger[{-2, 2}] f + RandomInteger[{-1, 1}] g + 
  RandomInteger[{-6, 6}] h + RandomInteger[{-6, 6}] i + 
  RandomInteger[{-6, 6}] j + RandomInteger[{-6, 6}] k + 
  RandomInteger[{-1, 1}] l), {go, 1, 8}] // Expand;
```

Let's make it **not** a polynomial in `a` by replacing the 1000th term with `Sin[a]`:

```
myPoly = ReplacePart[myPoly, 1000 -> Sin[a]];
```

So, now let's see how `` Internal`PolynomialFunctionQ `` and `PolynomialQ` perform:

```
AbsoluteTiming[Internal`PolynomialFunctionQ[myPoly, a]]
AbsoluteTiming[Internal`PolynomialFunctionQ[myPoly, b]]
AbsoluteTiming[Internal`PolynomialFunctionQ[myPoly, {a, b, c, d, e, f, g, h, i, j, k, l}]]
AbsoluteTiming[Internal`PolynomialFunctionQ[myPoly, {b, c, d, e, f, g, h, i, j, k, l}]]
(*  {0.033989, False}  *)
(*  {0.032627, True}   *)
(*  {0.056368, False}  *)
(*  {0.074603, True}   *)
```

and

```
AbsoluteTiming[PolynomialQ[myPoly, a]]
AbsoluteTiming[PolynomialQ[myPoly, b]]
AbsoluteTiming[PolynomialQ[myPoly, {a, b, c, d, e, f, g, h, i, j, k, l}]]
AbsoluteTiming[PolynomialQ[myPoly, {b, c, d, e, f, g, h, i, j, k, l}]]
(*  {3.98786, False}  *)
(*  {4.00939, True}   *)
(*  {3.222, False}  *)
(*  {3.32597, True}   *)
```

It seems like `` Internal`PolynomialFunctionQ `` performs 100 times better than `PolynomialQ` when checking for polynomialness in one variable, and about 50 times better for multiple variables.

Is anyone aware of this?  Is `` Internal`PolynomialFunctionQ `` a low-level version of `PolynomialQ`?

Comment: I doubt anyone can answer this, since it requires looking at the source code of the Wolfram Research Mathematica implementation of these algorithms, which only those who work at Wolfram are able to do.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

First note they are not equivalent:

```
PolynomialQ[x + x[1], x]
Internal`PolynomialFunctionQ[x + x[1], x]
(*
  True
  False
*)
```

Second note that `PolynomialQ` does a lot of checking:

```
Trace[
 PolynomialQ[x^2 Sin[y], x],
 TraceInternal -> True]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

If you care to, you can verify that every factor of every term seems to be checked:

```
With[{e = (a + 2 b + 3 c + 4 y)^2 // Expand},
 Trace[
  PolynomialQ[e, x],
  TraceInternal -> True]
 ]
```

What exactly this checking consists of seems to be inaccessible.  I've seen `` Integrate`FakeIntervalElement `` before, but I don't know what it's for or why it is used here.

On the OP's example, 600,000 expressions are checked, I suppose:

```
Count[myPoly, a | b | c | d | e | f | g | h | i | j | k | l, Infinity]
(*  602194  *)
```

Probably `` Internal`PolynomialFunctionQ `` is meant for a narrower range of use and goes straight to work on determining whether the variables appear only in nonnegative powers, etc.